# Create SSRS report showing a running historical count of subscription failure for each RDL and subscription (if multiple)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

We have a subscription that sends out daily that shows the previous days worth of subscription failures. But now we want to show a historical count for each failure as well (with possibily a drill through option of what the failure actually was)

```
if object_id('tempdb..#a') is not null drop table #a
SELECT LEFT(ca.[Path],CHARINDEX('/',SUBSTRING(ca.[Path],2,255))) RootPath
     , ca.[Name]
     , c.[Description]
     , c.ExtensionSettings
     --, LEFT(c.[Description],225) + '...' AS SubsDescripiton
     , c.LastStatus 
     , cu.UserName AS CreatedByUserName
     , mu.UserName AS ModifiedByUserName
     , c.LastRunTime
     , c.ModifiedDate
into #a
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions] c
LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] ca ON ca.ItemID = c.Report_OID
LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] cu ON cu.UserID = c.OwnerID
LEFT JOIN [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users] mu ON mu.UserID = c.ModifiedByID
WHERE c.LastRunTime >= DATEADD(hh,-24,getdate())
ORDER BY 1,2;



select * 
from #a
where [Description] <> 'DupeCheck'-- ignore this...this is is a good thing if it fails but it is uniquely for our RS 
AND LastStatus like '%; [1-9]% errors%'
or LastStatus like '%failure%'
or LastStatus  = 'An error has occurred during report processing.'
or LastStatus = 'The subscription contains parameter values that are not valid.'
or LastStatus LIKE 'Error: %'

/*
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[Schedule]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog2]
select top 100 * from [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog3]
```

*/

Comment: Please only tag the relevant version of SSRS not multiple (unless you actually need it for both version).

Comment: And what actually is your question?